# Atualizar links dos Posts pelo banco de dados

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

Olá, boa noite. Estou com um problema e queria uma ajuda.

Dentro de cada post meu eu tenho um link. Exemplo:

Post1 tenho o link: https://google.com
Post2 tenho o link: https://face.com
Post3 tenho o link: https://yt.com
Post4 tenho o link: https://gma.com

Eu preciso adicionar um "https://site.com/src=" na frente dos link. E isso eu até consegui. O problema é que dentro do post ele mostra lá, atualizado, mas eu tenho que clicar em "Atualizar" o post, para de fato ele atualizar a alteração que eu fiz.

Então queria saber se tem alguma forma de que eu possa alterar os link de todos os posts e não precisar depois abrir cada post e clicar em "Atualizar" para que então o link seja atualizado.

Comment: Como você fez pra alterar todas as urls e colocar o https://site.com/src= antes dos links? baseado na sua resposta, talvez eu possa ajudar

Comment: Eu baixei esse plugin: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Então eu substitui todos os link por ele. Ai ele altera. Só que quando eu acesso o post, ta lá atualizado, mas é como se ficasse saldo no modo "rascunho", ai tenho que clicar em atualizar para poder atualizar de fato. Só que isso é muito chato quando se tem centenas de posts.

Comment: Eu recomendo que você procure por "Replace images url wordpress" e tente aplicar o conceito pros posts, se você souber SQL você vai conseguir, se não souber SQL ou não se sentir muito confiante me avise aqui no comentário que eu respondo com a Query pra você atualizar todos os posts automaticamente, sem precisar entrar neles e atualizar manualmente

Comment: Se puder me ajudar com a Query, cara, seria muito util. Pq só falta isso mesmo...só falta atualizar todos os posts automaticamente,

Comment: Se você tiver acesso ao *phpmyadmin*, é só selecionar a tabela **wp_posts**, depois clicar em **Pesquisar**  e depois em **Find and replace**.

Comment: Eu faço isso, ele mudo no BD, mas tipo, eu tenho que acessar o post e clicar em "Atualizar" para que então seja alterado.

Comment: Tem como você listar os plugins ativos? Vai ajudar a galera a investigar o problema.